# How can I calculate with motor parameters?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I'll try to choose an electric motor for lifting weight but I am a little bit lost by the motor parameters. Sometimes I see torque: x Nm, but shouldn't that depend on the size of the gear I put on the axis? Sometimes I see force: y N, but shouldn't that depend on the gears and linear actuator I use? What I need is lifting 30kg, which requires at least 300N force. Can somebody clarify how can I use these motor parameters in my calculations?

Answer (score 1):

The torque specified for the motor usually corresponds to the maximum driveshaft or spindle torque. This torque may be stepped up or down by using a gear drive upstream of the load. The forces specified is the maximum force applied to the wires in the winding of the motor and does not directly depend on the gearing used downstream of it.